# calling code behind c# method from jquery ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to call code behind method from jquery ajax call but it doesnt hit break point on that methhod. what i am missing ?

js

```
$('#btn_Submit').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxExecute.aspx/CAO2',
            data: 'Guardian=' + $('#txtGuardianName').val() + '&CIFID=' + $('#txtCIFID').val() + '&EmploymentType=' + encodeURIComponent($('#cmbEmploymentType').val()) + '&NatureIncome=' + encodeURIComponent($('#cmbIncomeNature').val()) + '&Occupation=' + encodeURIComponent($('#cmbOccupation').val()),
            cache: false,
            context: document.body,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {

            }
        });
}
```

ajaxExecute.aspx.cs

```
public partial class ajaxExecute : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static void CAO2(string Guardian, string CIFID, string EmploymentType, string NatureIncome, string Occupation)
    {
            //Some Code
        //No breakpoint hit here
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //Some Code
        // Got Breakpoint here
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't set a breakpoint on a comment.

Comment: Fire up Fiddler and see what it tells you.

Comment: Pass data as JSON string

Comment: Haven't you forgotten a couple of equal signs? E.g: `&CIFID=`

Comment: @Niklas Corrected But of no use :(

Comment: @Dan-o downloaded & installed fiddler.m new to it can you tell me what to post here ? i am able to see my request in it

Comment: Fiddler is well documented.

Comment: @Dan-o My Parameter Values are properly being sent in header. i am able to see those values in WebForms -> Body

Comment: Haven't you an error in browser's console? You can receiving 404 error in case when url is incorrect

Comment: @Sarrus No Error on console because request path is correct and data is being sent (i guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send data as JSON:

```
$('#btn_Submit').click(function () {

   var request = {
     Guardian : $('#txtGuardianName').val(),
     CIFID : $('#txtCIFID').val(),
     EmploymentType : encodeURIComponent($('#cmbEmploymentType').val(),
     NatureIncome : encodeURIComponent($('#cmbIncomeNature').val()),
     Occupation : encodeURIComponent($('#cmbOccupation').val()
   };    

   var strRequest = JSON.stringify(request);  

   $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxExecute.aspx/CAO2',
            data: strRequest,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",  
            cache: false,
            context: document.body,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {

            }
        });
   }
```

Comment: It worked. But why it didnt in my case ? does it because it takes data only in json ?

Comment: not sure, but i think that your webmethod waits for 5 strings, but doesn't become them.

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
var dataString = JSON.stringify({ 
    Guardian : $('#txtGuardianName').val(), 
    CIFID : $('#txtCIFID').val(), 
    EmploymentType : encodeURIComponent($('#cmbEmploymentType').val(),
    NatureIncome : encodeURIComponent($('#cmbIncomeNature').val()),
    Occupation : encodeURIComponent($('#cmbOccupation').val()
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxExecute.aspx/CAO2",
    data: dataString,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
       alert("Success");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try to Json-ify you input data.
something like (not tested):
`data: JSON.stringify({ Guardian: $('#txtGuardianName').val(), CIFID: $('#txtCIFID').val() ... })`